# Unable to launch sparkR on cmd or rstudio

Tags: r, cmd, apache-spark

I have recently downloaded spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6 and am trying to run it on my personal laptop and running the following command at the location :

```
C:\Apache\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6` > `.\bin\sparkR
```

it is throwing an error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

It is also not running on the RStudio, on running the following command,

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Apache/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
```

it is throwing an error

> Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") : 
>     JVM is not ready after 10 seconds

Version of software which I am using are:

Rstudio: 0.99.489

R: 3.1.2

Comment: Try deleting a few `@echo off` to see what exactly happens in the scripts.

Comment: no effect, getting same error

Comment: I didn't expect it to solve the problem, I'm looking for more debug information.

Comment: Have you installed ``rJava``?